# apt-get install unable to locate package python-urllib

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, urllib, urllib3

```
sudo apt-get install python-urllib    
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done    
E: Unable to locate package python-urllib
```

Help me please

Comment: So what are you really trying to install? requests? urllib3?

Comment: Jessie has a [`python-urllib3`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python-urllib3); maybe that's what you're looking for? In any case, use `apt search` if you don't know the name of a given package.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you don't already have this package built-in to your OS:

```
>>> import urllib
```